# Index out of range mistake

Tags: python

I'm doing a project and me and my partner are working on the same file. so I created a loop to either read the file for mac or for pc.

I don't know why I have the "list index out of range" mistake

```
import os
import pandas

path_main = [i for i in (r"C:\Users\charlottelongpre\Desktop", "/Users/username/Desktop") if os.path.exists(i)][0]

path_file = path_main + '/' + "DataBaseZenOuStresse_1.xlsx"

stress_df = pandas.read_excel(path_file, sheet_name="REAL_Database_projet_PSY4016")
```

Comment: Maybe none of `"C:\Users\charlottelongpre\Desktop", "/Users/username/Desktop"` exists? Did you forget to replace `"username"` with something useful?

Comment: If `path_main ` is an empty list, then it won't have an index `[0]`

Comment: Please provide the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

If neither of the paths in that tuple exist then the outer list will be empty and you'll get an `IndexError` when trying to get the first element.

Note also that a more succinct approach would be to use the `next` function ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)), but that won't help here as you'd get a `StopIteration` exception instead.

For a more robust solution you can use the `os.path.join` method to create file/directory paths that work on the current operating system and you can use `pathlib.Path.home()` to get the home directory.

For example:

```py
import os
import pathlib

home_dir = str(pathlib.Path.home())
main_path = os.path.join(home_dir, "Desktop")

file_name = "DataBaseZenOuStresse_1.xlsx"
file_path = os.path.join(main_path, file_name)
```

Of course, you may want to add handling for missing the `"Desktop"` directory, but that seems less likely at least for this use-case. You can also just let `pandas.read_excel` tell you if the file is missing.